# How do I insert a value to a specefic row?

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to do an insert

```
database::query("INSERT INTO cr VALUES ('$flname', '$email', '$pass', '$ext')");
```

and how to find a row

```
database::query("SELECT * FROM cr WHERE email='$email'")
```

but how do I do both, i.e. select a specefic row and then insert/update that value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update MySQL row in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670964/how-do-i-update-mysql-row-in-php)

Comment: Do you want to **update** an existing row, or to insert a new row into a specific position on the table? The latter is not possible / makes no sense in SQL

Comment: If you want to prevent SQL injection when storing user values into the database, you may want to look into prepared statements.

Comment: This question is rather vague

Comment: Do you perhaps want to insert a row using data pulled from elsewhere in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
database::query("update cr set FileName='$flname', Email='$email', Pass='$pass', Ext='$ext' where email='$email');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) an existing row. To avoid injection, you escape variables with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and/or by preparing and [binding parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 1):

Inserting data into a specific row requires that this row exists; in that case you perform an [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) which usually has a WHERE condition just like a SELECT has.

To avoid SQL injection you want to use mysql_real_escape_string() on your variables; for numeric data it is also a good idea to cast to the desired type. Another option would be using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to change field in existing row:

```
UPDATE cr SET col = 'val' WHERE id = x
```

or if you wan't to insert or update:

```
REPLACE cr VALUES ($id, '$flname', '$email', '$pass', '$ext')
```

in the latter you have to put unique key on id (or other column)

there is also

```
INSERT INTO cr (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col = 'val'
```