# how do you update a row in mysql with php from a user

Tags: php, mysql

```PHP
$pos = $_POST['pos'];
$played = $_POST['played'];
$won = $_POST['won'];
$drawn = $_POST['drawn'];
$lost = $_POST['lost'];
$goalsfor = $_POST['goalsfor'];
$goalsag = $_POST['goalsag'];
$goaldif = $_POST['goalsdif'];
$points = $_POST['points'];



if (mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE division2 SET Pos ='".$pos."', played ='".$played."', won ='".$won."', drawn ='".$drawn."', lost ='".$lost."', goalsfor ='".$goalsfor."', goalsag ='".$goalsag."', goalsdif ='".$goaldif."', points ='".$points."',  WHERE team = Treaty Celtic") === true) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Row Successfully Inserted")';
    echo '</script>';
    include("index.html");
```

This is what i have so far but i keep getting "error inserting row" 
I want to update the entire row from a user input using $_Post in php.

Comment: *Errr...* there's no code (yet).

Comment: Where is your code?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update MySQL row in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670964/how-do-i-update-mysql-row-in-php)

Comment: try this: WHERE team = 'Treaty Celtic'

Comment: just tried WHERE team = 'Treaty Celtic' didn't work thanks @Azeez Kallayi

Comment: Please check your column name is Pos or pos. Because all athor fields are small cases..

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two errors in your query additional `,` at the end of field list and missing `'` in where condition. Update it to following:

```
if (mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE division2 SET Pos ='".$pos."', played ='".$played."', won ='".$won."', drawn ='".$drawn."', lost ='".$lost."', goalsfor ='".$goalsfor."', goalsag ='".$goalsag."', goalsdif ='".$goaldif."', points ='".$points."'  WHERE team = 'Treaty Celtic'") === true) {
```

Comment: Tried that still getting error inserting rows.

Comment: what does `mysqli_error($db)` gives to you in case of error, try that in else section, that may help you

Comment: it gave me the error unknown column in field set and i checked my DB columns and found I had misspelled two columns in my php, so i fixed that and it works now, the error reporting helped a lot  thanks @Dharmesh Patel

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE team = Treaty Celtic` is one of the problems here.

That needs to be wrapped in quotes, since we're dealing with a string.

`WHERE team = 'Treaty Celtic'`

Those 2 syntax errors would have been caught had you checked for errors.

Read up on string literals:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html

and checking for errors would have thrown you a syntax error about it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

and a trailing comma in

```
points ='".$points."', <<< THERE
```

**Remove it.**

Also make sure those POST arrays have values with their respective name attributes in the HTML form.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Add `or die(mysqli_error($db))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Or as an `else` to the `if`:

```
else { 
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($db); 
}
```

Seeing now that it's not working for you, make sure that you are using the same MySQL API as your query, being `mysqli_`.

Different APIs do not intermix.

---

**And as bonus:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: I wrapped WHERE team = Treaty Celtic in quotes and error reporting is at the top of my files, still getting error inserting rows.

Comment: @Walshe007 I need to know the exact error.

Comment: @Walshe007 also, `Treaty Celtic` that must be the exact string with no trailing spaces. `Treaty Celtic` and `Treaty celtic` isn't the same thing.

Comment: @Walshe007 add an `else` for the `if` - As in `else { echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($db); }` and tell me what you see, something I have in my answer. I can't help you if I don't know what the exact error is. Same for error reporting, if any.

Comment: @Walshe007 make up your mind as to which one you're going to accept. You've been going back and forth with this twice already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that a POST has been sent from the user form. Use the  `if (!empty($_POST)){...}` to confirm whether the post has happened or Not. Move your entire block code to the if block.

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
   //your entire code here... 
}else{
   echo "No POST !!!";
}
```

May be there is some columns with NOT NULL attribute which caused the error... Good Luck..